# Should I drop out of the IB Diploma Program if I am about to graduate with an associate's degree?

Tags: united-states, undergraduate, community-college

I'm a junior in high school who goes to an IB (International Baccalaureate) school in the US. I also have been taking enough community college classes to graduate with an AA in Computer Science before finishing high school and I believe that any damage dropping out of the program would be completely nullified by a full associate's degree. In addition to this, I am currently a software engineer (part-time) and I think that I wouldn't have enough time to manage all three things in my senior year with the EE, CAS Project, and 2 extra classes I would have to take as a full diploma student.

Is it a good idea to continue with an IB Certificate, SWE position, and Associates Degree in lieu of staying on the IB Full Diploma possibly having to sacrifice completing the degree and/or staying in my software engineering position in my senior year.

IMPORTANT FACTOR: I intend to go to UC Berkeley as my #1 choice so a fairly selective but not ultra-selective school. I don't really want to go to a private school. I am attending a California community college which gets me guaranteed 1:1 transfer of credits to any UC school. That's why the main point of contention I'm facing is that I might not be able to complete the degree and/or stay on as a software engineer (which is extremely highly viewed by companies and likely also by schools) if I stay in the IB Diploma vs dropping to the IB Certificate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I have tried to make your title closer to context of the actual question. Feel free to rollback if you disagree with the edit.

Comment: Undergraduate admissions is off-topic.  Once you have a BA, nobody will care about your AA or IB anymore.  Do whatever helps you learn or advance your career goals.  Presumably you cannot get the IB diploma until after Berkeley decides if they want to admit you.  In that case the IB diploma itself will not change their decision.

Comment: Cheap transfer credits from a community college are in the financial interests of most students.